# starts with and exact word regex pattern for postgresql

Tags: java, regex, postgresql

I have these student_id(int) data

```
20001001 
20001002 
20001003 
20001004 
20001005
```

I want to use a regex pattern wherein;

1. when '2000' is used, all the data will be displayed (starts with)
2. when '20001002' is used, only the specific data is displayed (exact match)

I tried using this regex pattern to meet my objectives;

```
'^[X]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*$'
```

where x is a string variable, it's value depends on what data I want to display; either "2000" or more specific "20001002"

However, my second objective(exact match) is not being met, what changes with my regex pattern should be made to met my 2 objectives?

I'm using Java JDBC and Postgresql.

```
public static ResultSet searchStudentQuery(Connection connection, String dbTable, String searchCriteria)
        throws SQLException {

    String regex = "^[" + searchCriteria.trim().toUpperCase() + "]+[0-9a-zA-Z]*$";
    PreparedStatement searchStudent = connection.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT * FROM " + dbTable + " WHERE CAST(student_id AS TEXT) ~ ? OR first_name ~ ? OR last_name ~ ?;");

    searchStudent.setString(1, regex);
    searchStudent.setString(2, regex);
    searchStudent.setString(3, regex);
    return searchStudent.executeQuery();

}
```

EDIT: I want to do this in a postresql query manner if possible

Comment: Try `20001002|X[0-9]*` with `String.matches()`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited my question, I want it to do it in a postgresql query, is it possible? I added my code snippet

Comment: I do not think you need to create a character class for the `searchCriteria` in the regex, unless you want to match `ARM` with `RAM`. Try `String regex = "^" + searchCriteria.trim().toUpperCase() + "[0-9a-zA-Z]*$";`. Note **the `[` and `]+` are removed**.

Comment: That is what exactly I'm using, but it doesn't seem to find an exact match of the integers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked on my Java JDBC application! but I was wondering why it had an "syntax error at or near [" when I run the query on the postgresql database. This is the query I used, ^20001002[0-9a-zA-Z]*$

Comment: No idea what an issue can be but the `^20001002[0-9a-zA-Z]*$` regex is a correct POSIX regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a character class with the square brackets

```
"^[" + searchCriteria.trim().toUpperCase() + "]+"....
  ^                                           ^
```

and then set a `+` quantifier after it. Thus, you do not account neither for the order, nor the amount of characters in the `searchCriteria` string. You can match `RAM` with `[ARM]+` regex, or even `RAMARM`, `AMRAM`, etc.

You can just remove the `[` and `]+` to enforce a strict pattern matching ("exact" word match):

```
String regex = "^" + searchCriteria.trim().toUpperCase() + "[0-9a-zA-Z]*$";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)